# How to execute actionStream on a notification when application is in terminated state with awesome_notifications in flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, awesome-notifications

I have a flutter application that receives FCM Data messages.

On each data message, I create a respective notification locally using the **awesome_notifications** library. I have 2 action buttons on the notification. The action button click navigates me to a specific page when the application is in the *foreground* or *background(paused)*.

But, the same click action doesn't work when the app is *terminated/killed*. Instead of navigating to some page, it just opens the application's homepage.

I'm listening to actionStream, but it seems it doesn't work when the app is terminated.

If anyone has a solution to this, it would be beneficial!

Comment: Have you got any solution

Comment: I don't have a solution yet